# Google Chrome does not preview PDF in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

Google Chrome does not preview PDF but automatically downloads the PDF. I checked the settings - everything is ok.

Firefox - shows the preview and does not auto-download it.

What I use:

```
 <embed
     src={pdf-url}
     type="application/pdf"
     width="100%"
     height="200px"
 />
<object
     data={pdf-url}
     width="300"
     height="200"
/>
```

React-pdf - had problem because couldn't run in on webpack 3

Any suggestions how to fix it?

HTTP Response:

```
Request URL: server-url
Request method: GET
Status code: 200 
Remote address: **address**
Referrer policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

accept-ranges: bytes
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
cache-control: max-age=14400
cf-cache-status: REVALIDATED
cf-ray: 78ae088b5e152d37-KBP
content-length: 121539
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Tue, 17 Jan 2023 09:23:39 GMT
etag: "f469b7190540ebbc1504b7491c05c587"
last-modified: Fri, 14 Oct 2022 14:50:01 GMT
nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":url}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
```

Comment: What HTTP response headers is your server giving for the request to the PDF resource?

Comment: @CBroe I added HTTP response

Comment: `content-type: application/octet-stream` tells the client, "this is an arbitrary stream of byte values, the type/meaning of which is unknown." Looks like Chrome gives this preference over the `type` attribute of the `embed` element. Try and get your server to respond with `content-type: application/pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <embed
        src='assets/test.pdf'
        type="application/pdf"
        width="100%"
        min-height="200px"
      />
```

it work's fine in both Google Chrome and Firefox

just check your src address and make sure to not put / at the end of it

Comment: I get src from backend